# Normalizing a table with duplicate rows and many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-normalization

I am designing the database for an accounting system, currently working on the Expenses table.

According to IRS rules, whenever you update a row in any accounting table, you need to cancel out the existing row by negating its values, and create a new row with the modified information, like so:

1. Set the row's Status flag to "Modified"
2. Create an identical copy of this row, with all Money fields negated, so that the sum of the two rows is 0
3. Create a 3rd row, identical to the first one, with the modified data

Each expense has an identity field called ID for internal identification purposes, and an ExpenseID field, which identifies the transaction to the users. The two cannot be the same, because

1. ExpenseID can be repeated twice if the transaction was modified and its row was duplicated.
2. ExpenseIDs MUST be consecutive and NEVER have gaps, while identity fields can skip numbers if a transaction is rolled back and the identity is not reseeded.
3. In general, I believe the primary key should have no business meaning whatsoever.

My problem is that there are other tables used to link these expenses Many-To-Many to other objects in our system. E.g.: each expense can be linked to documents, folders, users, etc.

So it looks something like this:

```
create table Expenses (
    ID int not null identity(1,1),
    ExpenseID int not null,
    Amount Money not null,
    Status tinyint not null,
    [...]
)

create table Expenses_Users (
    ExpenseID int not null,
    UserID int not null
)

alter table Expenses_Users add constraint FK_Expenses_Users_Expenses
foreign key (ExpenseID) references Expenses (ID)

alter table Expenses_Users add constraint FK_Expenses_Users_Users
foreign key (UserID) references Users (ID)
```

Now, because of the IRS guidelines, I have to duplicate not only rows in the Expenses table, but also in Expenses_Users, and any other table that links Expenses to other tables.

I have two ideas on how to solve this:

**Option One:** Normalize Expenses like this:

```
create table Expenses (
    ID int not null identity(1,1),
    ExpenseID int not null,
    Status tinyint not null,
    [...]
)

create table ExpensesNormalized (
    ExpenseID int not null,
    Amount Money not null
)

alter table ExpensesNormalized add constraint FK_ExpensesNormalized_Expenses
foreign key (ExpenseID) references Expenses(ExpenseID)
```

This means I'll only have to link external tables to Expenses, not ExpensesNormalized. Also, when updating an expense, I'll only duplicate and negate the data in ExpensesNormalized, which means I'll have far less redundant data in the Expenses table.

However, I'll have to use a JOIN clause every single time I SELECT from Expenses. I fear a performance hit because of this.

**Option Two:** Use the same tables I use now, but have the field Expenses_Users.ExpenseID point to the field Expenses.ExpenseID. This means that I won't have to duplicate any external objects because they'll point to ExpenseID, which may occur several times.

However, this will not be a real foreign key because SQL Server does not allow foreign keys to non-unique fields, so I'll have to implement foreign key logic in a trigger.

I'm having a hard time deciding between these two options. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Curious. Link to IRS rules?

Comment: I'm refering to the Israeli IRS rules. They are in Hebrew, unfortunately :-)

Comment: Ah. I see. (I used to read some Hebrew, but I'm definitely not interested in reading *IRS rules* in Hebrew.)

Comment: *"Set the row's Status flag to 'Modified'"* Does this refer to the new row or the old row?

Comment: The old row and the negated row.